# How to use http postasync in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to post a request to an API in asp.net. The code below does not give the same result like the code that I run in an ionic application, which I have also included below

Asp.net core 3.1 code

```
public class AccountInqueryParm
{
    public string message_id { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
    public string acc { get; set; }
    public string br { get; set; }
    public string appType { get; set; }
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>> BalanceInquery(AccountInqueryParm parm)
    {
        try
        {
            // return new[] { parm };
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = false };
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(mbBaseUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encoding(mbUsername + ':' + mbPassword));
                parm = new AccountInqueryParm 
                {
                    message_id = "7ac972059c7740c5855bc603facee4f2",
                    token = "541f21c5f730a024b72b7239df9b38055784ebf2", 
                    acc = "1100016", 
                    br = "00000", 
                    appType = "1"
                };
                StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parm), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                using (var response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress + "accountEnquiry", content))
                {
                    string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return new[] { apiResponse };
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

This is the ionic-angular code that works fine

```
MBServiceLocal() {
const msgid = '7ac972059c7740c5855bc603facee4f2';
const accNo = '1100016';
const brID = '00000';
const appTypeID = '1'
const tKen = '541f21c5f730a024b72b7239df9b38055784ebf2';
const url = 'api url';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username' + ':'+ 'password')
  })
 };

 const parmObject = { messageId: msgid, token: tKen, acc: accNo, br: brID, appType: appTypeID };

 this.http.post(url, parmObject, httpOptions)
          .subscribe(response => {
            console.log('MBIBService Result: ', response);
        }, error => {
          console.log('MBIBService server error: ' + error);
        });
```

}
}

How can I make c# code work the same way based on the ionic-angular code? I have tried several workarounds. For example, how can I pass httpOptions in asp.net httpclient postasync() method?

Comment: Unrelated: Do not create a new HttpClient on each call. Have it injected.

Comment: Actually, I get an error code from the API showing invalid parameter due to the following line of code StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parm), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");, but the equivalent code in typescript (under ionic-angular code section) does not report the error.

Comment: How does the api know about your source code? What does the error message say exactly?

Comment: I have the API documentation which shows in the response message that the parameter value I am passing to PostAsync() is invalid and the parameter value is from StringContent. However, when I pass an equivalent object in the typescript code in ionic-angular application the response is flawless. I was wondering what I am doing wrong in the ASP.NET core code that I presented in my post.

Comment: We cannot see all that. So we cannot comment on it. We only know what you present in the question. You may want to try some tool like wireshark to see what gets on the wire towards the API. Then you can diff the two and see where you have to tweak.